# How to hide sort option for a specific page in the Hybris

Tags: sorting, solr, hide, sap-commerce-cloud

I have 3 SolrSorts:

1. relevance
2. A-Z
3. Z-A

On the search page, there should be all of 3 sorts available. But on the category page just A-Z and Z-A. So how can I hide the relevance sort on the category page?

I have overridden the class **DefaultSolrProductSearchService** but there is nothing that could help me.
I think there should be something like a configuration in spring.xml?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this configurable from the backend so that tomorrow you can hide another field for a particular page from HMC/backoffice then you need to make a lot of changes right from the Model to backend to frontend. But if you want to simply hardcode this requirement, you can handle this easily on the frontend side. Like this...

1. Modify **searchresultsgridcomponent.jsp** to pass an additional flag to the pagination.tag. Which help us to identify search page vs category page.

Please note, you can find two references of **nav:pagination** in that file, please modify both with `isSearchPage="${true}"`.

```
<nav:pagination top="true"  supportShowPaged="${isShowPageAllowed}" supportShowAll="${isShowAllAllowed}"  searchPageData="${searchPageData}" searchUrl="${searchPageData.currentQuery.url}"  numberPagesShown="${numberPagesShown}" isSearchPage="${true}"/>
```

2. Repeat above step for **searchresultslistcomponent.jsp**
3. In the pagination.tag, decare the `isSearchPage` attribute and handle the sort option rendering login with the help of this flag.

Something like this

```
<%@ attribute name="isSearchPage" required="false" type="java.lang.Boolean" %>
<c:set var="isSeachPg" value="${empty isSearchPage ? false : isSearchPage}"/>
```

Let's allow relevance only for the search page.

```
<select id="sortOptions${top ? '1' : '2'}" name="sort" class="form-control">
    <option disabled><spring:theme code="${themeMsgKey}.sortTitle"/></option>
    <c:forEach items="${searchPageData.sorts}" var="sort">
        <c:if test="${isSeachPg || (not isSeachPg && fn:escapeXml(sort.code) != 'relevance')}">
            <option value="${fn:escapeXml(sort.code)}" ${sort.selected? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${not empty sort.name}">
                        ${fn:escapeXml(sort.name)}
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <spring:theme code="${themeMsgKey}.sort.${sort.code}"/>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </option>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```